# how to get database fields value from the sqlite database?

Tags: cocoa

I want to get fields name from the sqlite database in my mac desktop application.How it possible please help me.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the SQLite C API directly (which you shouldn't), you can use the [`sqlite_column_name()`](http://sqlite.org/c3ref/column_name.html) function to get the name of a column for a given index.  This works well with the [`sqlite_column_count()`](http://sqlite.org/c3ref/column_count.html) function.

If you're using the [Flying Meat Database](http://code.google.com/p/flycode/) wrapper (which you should), you can execute `PRAGMA table_info(myTable)`, and then iterate through the ResultSet.  The column name is at index 1.  In other words:

```
FMResultSet * infoRS = [db executeQuery:@"PRAGMA table_info(myTable)"];
while ([infoRS next]) {
    NSLog(@"Column #%d: %@", [infoRS intForColumnIndex:0], [infoRS stringForColumnIndex:1]);
}
```